# Using Branch.io together with Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm trying to figure out exactly what this code from the Branch.io documentation means

```
// Add the openURL and continueUserActivity functions
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    if (![RNBranch.branch application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
        // do other deep link routing for the Facebook SDK, Pinterest SDK, etc
    }
    return YES;
}
```

What is the best way to add in if I already have the FBSDK and am handling that with the return boolean handled?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                  ];

  if (![RNBranch.branch application:application openURL:url options:options]) {
    // do other deep link routing for the Facebook SDK, Pinterest SDK, etc
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Essentially, my question is what is the correct approach here when return handled and why is `return YES` used after the `if (![RNBranch...` and is it needed? What should I have it bearing in mind I'm already returning `BOOL handled`?

Answer (score 4):

Amruta from Branch here:

You should call the Branch SDK's openURL call before any other SDK call in your openURL method, to make sure the click is not consumed by some other application. If Branch is not able to handle the click, you can then try the Facebook SDK's call.

With regards to the return value for the openURL method, although iOS documentation states that openURL should return `Yes` if the click is handled successfully else should return `No` ([documentation ref](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622961-openurl)) during our testing Branch found a bug on Apple's end. If openURL returns false/No, the application stops responding to any future clicks. Hence, we recommend always returning `true/Yes` from the openURL method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first try the Branch routing, then, if it failed, try Facebook.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *) {

  // first try to open the deep link in our app
  if (![RNBranch.branch application:application openURL:url options:options]) {
    // failed — this is probably a deep link for some other application. Let’s try Facebook.
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
    ];
  }
  // succeeded, since Branch handled the deep link for us, returning YES.
  return YES;
}
```

If you’d like to add handlers beside Facebook, do it in the `if`.

Comment: Thanks, looks good - I'm not sure exactly I'll admit. The application may be opened using branching, and FBSDKApplicationDelegate is just used for the Facebook Analytics it seems, as actual login with Facebook is no longer used. I suppose actually I'm looking to log events without the Facebook Login side of things

With that in mind, if I still want to use Facebook analytics i.e. for active users and what not, is the ... `return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate` block of code needed?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/

Comment: Hey there! I think there's a typo in the FB return line. The final "];" should be one line down, no? I edited your answer the the typo caused my build to fail.